# Proper way to import json file to mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

I've been trying to use mongo with some data imported, but I'm not able to use it properly with my document description.

This is an example of the .json I import using mongoimport: https://gist.github.com/2917854

```
mongoimport -d test -c example data.json
```

I noticed that all my document it's imported to a unique object in spite of creating one of object for each shop.

That's why when I try to find a shop or anything I want to query, all the document is returned.

```
db.example.find({"shops.name":"x"})
```

I want to be able to query the db to obtain products by the id using dot notation something similar to:

```
db.example.find({"shops.name":"x","categories.type":"shirts","clothes.id":"1"}
```

The problem is that all the document is imported like a single object. The question is: How
do I need to import the object to obtain my desired result?

Comment: your link has an extra 'a' at the end

Comment: @ErenGüven Oops!Thanks for the warning! ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoimport) note that:

> This utility takes a single file that contains 1 JSON/CSV/TSV string per line and inserts it.

In the structure you are using -assuming the errors on the gist are fixed- you are essentially importing one document with only `shops` field.

After breaking the data into separate shop docs, import using something like (shops being the collection name, makes more sense than using `example`):

```
mongoimport -d test -c shops data.json
```

and then you can query like:

```
db.shops.find({"name":x,"categories.type":"shirts"})
```

Answer (score 23):

There is a parameter `--jsonArray`:

> Accept import of data expressed with multiple MongoDB document within a single JSON array

Using this option you can feed it an array, so you only need to strip the outer object syntax i.e. everything at the beginning until and including `"shops" :`, and the `}` at the end.

Myself I use a little tool called [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) that can extract the array from command line:

```
./jq '.shops' shops.json
```

Answer (score 11):

**IMPORT FROM JSON**

```
mongoimport --db "databaseName" --collection "collectionName" --type json --file "fileName.json" --jsonArray
```

JSON format should be in this format. (Array of Objects)

```
[
    { name: "Name1", msg: "This is msg 1" },
    { name: "Name2", msg: "This is msg 2" },
    { name: "Name3", msg: "This is msg 3" }
]
```

**IMPORT FROM CSV**

```
mongoimport --db "databaseName" --collection "collectionName" --type csv --file "fileName.csv" --headerline
```

More Info

https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/import-data/

Answer (score 1):

## Importing a JSON

The command `mongoimport` allows us to import human readable `JSON` in a specific database & a collection. To import a `JSON` data in a specific database & a collection, type `mongoimport -d databaseName -c collectionName jsonFileName.json`