# Importing json file in new fresh mnogodb

Tags: json, mongodb, osx-yosemite

I just want to ask how can I import this example.json file in new mongodb I expect to have each seassion object as row in the table I tried

```
mongoimport --db foo --collection myCollections < dataBuys.json
2015-05-07T21:19:15.828+0300    connected to: localhost
2015-05-07T21:19:18.831+0300    foo.myCollections   168.5 MB
2015-05-07T21:19:21.826+0300    foo.myCollections   168.5 MB
2015-05-07T21:19:24.828+0300    foo.myCollections   168.5 MB
2015-05-07T21:19:27.828+0300    foo.myCollections   168.5 MB
2015-05-07T21:19:28.849+0300    warning: attempting to insert document      with size 124.6 MB (exceeds 16.0 MB limit)
2015-05-07T21:19:28.986+0300    error inserting documents: write tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: broken pipe
2015-05-07T21:19:28.986+0300    imported 0 documents
```

and this

```
mongoimport -d mydb -c mycollection --jsonArray < dataBuys.json
2015-05-07T21:20:02.139+0300    connected to: localhost
2015-05-07T21:20:02.139+0300    Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source
2015-05-07T21:20:02.139+0300    imported 0 documents
```

The file I want to import have the following format and it size is 170mb for this one and 2.97GB for the other one.

```
{
"Sessions": {
"420374" : {
  "Purchases" : [
    {
      "Price" : "12462",
      "Quantity" : "1",
      "Timestamp" : "2014-04-06T18:44:58.314Z",
      "ItemId" : "214537888"
    },
    {
      "Price" : "10471",
      "Quantity" : "1",
      "Timestamp" : "2014-04-06T18:44:58.325Z",
      "ItemId" : "214537850"
    }
  ]
},

"281626" : {
  "Purchases" : [
    {
      "Price" : "1883",
      "Quantity" : "1",
      "Timestamp" : "2014-04-06T09:40:13.032Z",
      "ItemId" : "214535653"
    }
  ]
},

"420368" : {
  "Purchases" : [
    {
      "Price" : "6073",
      "Quantity" : "1",
      "Timestamp" : "2014-04-04T06:13:28.848Z",
      "ItemId" : "214530572"
    },
    {
      "Price" : "2617",
      "Quantity" : "1",
      "Timestamp" : "2014-04-04T06:13:28.858Z",
      "ItemId" : "214835025"
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

Do I have to reformat the json ? is it possible to make it work like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first error message says:
warning: attempting to insert document      with size 124.6 MB (exceeds 16.0 MB limit)

This implies you are trying to insert a document that is 124.6MB in size.
A json document starts with an open brace character "{" and ends with a closed brace  character "}".  The error message implies that you have 124.6MB between such characters.

I think you need to examine your input file and verify that each session object is defined as a separate document - another words starts and ends with a brace.

I suspect the problem is that the session objects are in fact embedded in a master document - sort of a container document.  This would make mongoimport try to map the master container document to its collection - and not the session objects as you require.

Comment: I think Pat is correct, your current format won't work. Check out another alternative format here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16677630/371273

Comment: so the simple answer is mongodb can't import json in this format it should be array with lines with objects like this {"stupid" : "bla bla", "megaStupid 
":"bla bla"}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for verifying that your GeoJSON file is accurate, you could use [Geojsonlint](http://geojsonlint.com/), [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and so on.

After than, to import your data into your collection, use [Mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/):

`mongoimport --db MY_DATABASE_NAME -c MY_COLLECTION_NAME --type json --file "MY_GEOJSON_FILENAME"`

Replace the 3 variables above whith your valid names. Obviously, make sure that your current directory contains the file.

Profit! :)